# RPI Zero - software installation from SD card

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi-zero

I bought a RPI Zero for some projects. The problem is that this version of RPI does not have WIFI and only USB is used for keyboard.

Is it possible to install software like `pip3` / `guizero` / ... via SD card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but I don't recommend it. You can download the .deb files, copy them to the sd card, and install them using

```
dpkg -i <package name>
```

But this has several disadvantages. You cannot use apt package manager without internet connection. You need to install all the dependencies as well, thus can be 10 packages or even much more. And you would need to update manually as well ... a nightmare.

Your options apart from this, you need an USB hub:

1) Get a cheap wifi stick (about $5)
2) If you have your mobile phone, you can enable USB Tethering. This will share your phones internet connection with the RPi.
Comment if you need my help to configure this. But it's easy.

Comment: Thank you for the command. I am affraid that option 1, 2 and 3 are not applicable here - there is no Ethernet on RPI Zero, if I would connect wifi stick there will be no room for the keyboard - so I will not be able to do anything and for the 3rd - I am unsure if I can do this without wifi module on RPI.

Comment: Currently I am trying to connect RPI to PC... maybe this will help somehow.

Comment: Get a cheap usb Hub. This works as a " usb port multiplier". You can connect multiple devices to one port with this method. If you use usb tethering you can connect to the device with vnc viewer app, you don't need a keyboard or usb Hub with this method.

Comment: Here is a tutorial for usb tethering. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=90728 Set it up and start vnc server (You can activate it in interfacing options on raspi-config), unplug the keyboard, plug in phone, go to usb tethering in preferences, activate it, download vncviewer app on phone, click new connection, type hostname:5900 (hostname is your rpis hostname, default 'raspberrypi') and connect. You will get virtual desktop keyboard and mouse on the phone. By the way, even if you manage to install pip3, it does not work without internet connection!

Comment: Well I decided to go with additonal hub and wifi stick. 
The installation from SD card was painful and connection by USB (to PC) was raising some driver issues on my computer and after 3 days of struggle I was unable to share Internet correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `qemu static` along with `chroot` on the root file system of your SD card as a preparation phase.

Here is a small script to do it:

```
cp /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static <sdcard>/usr/bin/
chroot <sdcard> bash -c "apt-get install ..."
rm <sdcard>/usr/bin/qemu-aarch64-static
```

You can also have a look at: https://wiki.debian.org/RaspberryPi/qemu-user-static